How to interpolate pandas time series using different timestamps
I am looking for a function
pandas_interpolate(df: pd.DataFrame, newTime: pd.DatetimeIndex, method: str = 'linear') -> pd.DataFrame

that would take an existing dataframe with a DatetimeIndex index, and return a new dataframe with index given by newTime. For each column, the values of the new dataframe should be evaluated by interpolating the values of the original dataframe. In spirit, this function should behave similarly to numpy.interp. I am aware of the method pandas.DataFrame.interpolate, however, it interpolates existing NAN values, and does not accept a new index as an argument.
So far I have 2 ideas

Append new index and the end of the dataframe with all values being NAN, then drop duplicate indices for the exact timestamps that already exist, then use pandas interpolate method, then only select rows with the new index.
Convert dataframe to numpy array. Loop over columns, use numpy interpolate, then convert back to dataframe.

Both would surely work, but are quite ugly. Is there an intended way to do this?
Edit: Minimal example
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3]},
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01',
                                          '2024-01-15',
                                          '2024-01-30']))

newTime = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='1D')

which results in newTime
DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04',
           '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08',
           '2024-01-09', '2024-01-10', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-12',
           '2024-01-13', '2024-01-14', '2024-01-15', '2024-01-16',
           '2024-01-17', '2024-01-18', '2024-01-19', '2024-01-20',
           '2024-01-21', '2024-01-22', '2024-01-23', '2024-01-24',
           '2024-01-25', '2024-01-26', '2024-01-27', '2024-01-28',
           '2024-01-29', '2024-01-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

Then the expected output of the function should be (I have hacked it togethere here)
pd.DataFrame({'value': np.interp(np.arange(1, 31), [1,15,30], [1,2,3])}, index=newTimes)

which is
value
2024-01-01  1.000000
2024-01-02  1.071429
2024-01-03  1.142857
2024-01-04  1.214286
2024-01-05  1.285714
2024-01-06  1.357143
2024-01-07  1.428571
2024-01-08  1.500000
2024-01-09  1.571429
2024-01-10  1.642857
2024-01-11  1.714286
2024-01-12  1.785714
2024-01-13  1.857143
2024-01-14  1.928571
2024-01-15  2.000000
2024-01-16  2.066667
2024-01-17  2.133333
2024-01-18  2.200000
2024-01-19  2.266667
2024-01-20  2.333333
2024-01-21  2.400000
2024-01-22  2.466667
2024-01-23  2.533333
2024-01-24  2.600000
2024-01-25  2.666667
2024-01-26  2.733333
2024-01-27  2.800000
2024-01-28  2.866667
2024-01-29  2.933333
2024-01-30  3.000000

Important NOTE: Original values may be offset with respect to new values, for example, they may be given with hourly precision. So it is possible that no points of the original index match to the new index.

Please provide a [mre] with input/expected output for clarity.

And yes, you would need to use one of those approaches.

No, interpolate is not designed to be similar to numpy.interp. It is rather a method to fill the existing NA values.
Yes, you need to add the indices with Index.union, then reindex and interpolate, finally select the desired indices (e.g. with loc).
It's not so ugly if you use indexes:
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3]},
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01',
                                          '2024-01-15',
                                          '2024-01-30']))

new_indices = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-10', '2024-01-16'])

out = (df.reindex(df.index.union(new_indices))
         .interpolate('time').loc[new_indices]
      )

Output:
               value
2024-01-10  1.642857
2024-01-16  2.066667

If you want to ignore the existing indices, add a drop:
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3]},
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01',
                                          '2024-01-15',
                                          '2024-01-30']))

new_indices = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-10', '2024-01-15'])

out = (df.drop(new_indices, errors='ignore')
         .reindex(df.index.union(new_indices))
         .interpolate('time').loc[new_indices]
      )

Output:
               value
2024-01-10  1.620690
2024-01-15  1.965517  # original 2024-01-15 is ignored

If a method should behave like numpy.interp, this should probably be reindex. You can already map the nearest value:
df.reindex(new_indices, method='nearest')

#             value
# 2024-01-10      2
# 2024-01-16      2

I guess there could be a method='interpolate' (or rather one of the valid options for interpolate's method parameter).

Another problem specific to method='interpolate' is that (according to the documentation) it requires data to be uniformly spaced, which is not the case. Does the 'time' method work as a linear interpolation in this case? Or is there an alternative?

The index and time methods use the index for a linear interpolation. If you want to convince yourself, change 2024-01-15 in the example df to another date ;)

In my previous comment, I meant method='linear'. Sorry for confusion, it was a typo

Absolute sadness. I have implemented your suggestion and my numpy idea. On 1 million rows Series, your method is 40x slower on method='linear' and 10x slower on method='previous' (using ffill() for pandas and scipy.interpolate in the other case). It looks like hacking things together still has merit. I'll add my analysis as an answer later today if I have a moment.
